# Как "прорисовывать" svg-фигуру

Tags: анимация, svg

Есть `svg` фигура

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0" class="grey-circle" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 115 115" enable-background="new 0 0 115 115" xml:space="preserve">
    <g opacity="0.15">
        <path class="grey-circle-path" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M57.5,3C87.6,3,112,27.4,112,57.5S87.6,112,57.5,112S3,87.6,3,57.5S27.4,3,57.5,3 M57.5,0   C25.7,0,0,25.7,0,57.5S25.7,115,57.5,115S115,89.3,115,57.5S89.3,0,57.5,0L57.5,0z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Как реализовать анимацию прорисовки фигуры? 

Какие свойства нужно использовать?

**P.S.** Нужно не зарисовывать фигуру, а именно анимировать отрисовку координат как в этом [Примере](https://jwn.gr/)

```
<svg version="1.0" class="animated-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"  enable-background="new 0 0 77 187" xml:space="preserve">
                                        <path class="lolly-pop-path" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M68.3,61v-0.3C62.3,68.8,51.4,74,39.8,74C19.5,74,3,58.1,3,38.5S19.6,3,39.9,3c15,0,27.9,8.6,33.7,21H77 C71.1,9.9,56.7,0,40,0C17.9,0,0,17.2,0,38.5C0,59.8,17.9,77,40,77c13.4,0,25.2-6.3,32.4-16H68.3z"/>
                                        <line class="lolly-pop-line" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="3.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="39.7" y1="74" x2="39.7" y2="187"/>
                                    </svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот тут есть подробное описание https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/  . Вам понадобится подходящее svg-изображение: вся картинка должна быть представлена линиями, нарисованными тегом path. Идея в том, что линии задается свойство strokeDasharray, это значит, что линия рисуется пунктиром вот так - - - - - -. Для анимации длины закрашенного участка и пробела делаются равными длины всей линии path, устанавливается смещение strokeDashoffset тоже равное длине path. Во время анимации мы уменьшаем смещение strokeDashoffset до нуля, повесив до этого обычную анимацию css.

```js
function animateSvg() {
  var path = document.querySelector('g path');
  var length = path.getTotalLength();
  // Clear any previous transition
  path.style.transition = path.style.transition =
    'none';
  // Set up the starting positions
  path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
  // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
  // picks up the starting position before animating
  path.getBoundingClientRect();
  // Define our transition
  path.style.transition = path.style.transition =
    'stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out';
  // Go!
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
}
```

```html
<div style="background:#eee">
<svg class="squiggle-animated">
<g opacity="0.15">
    <path class="grey-circle-path" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="0" d="M57.5,3C87.6,3,112,27.4,112,57.5S87.6,112,57.5,112S3,87.6,3,57.5S27.4,3,57.5,3 M57.5,0   C25.7,0,0,25.7,0,57.5S25.7,115,57.5,115S115,89.3,115,57.5S89.3,0,57.5,0L57.5,0z"/>
</g>
</svg>
 </div>
<button onclick="animateSvg()">Animate</button>
```

Comment: Странно, попытался всунуть в свою вёрстку и не работает..

Comment: Покажите ваш svg. Рисовка должна быть с помощью path. В теории так можно не только с path, но мой пример работает только с path

Comment: Прикрепил код к вопросу, нужно отрисовывать 2 элемента

Comment: Вы должны подготовить ваше изображение. Все должно быть отрисовано тегом path, в идеале не закрашено fill="none" у линий должен быть цвет и толщина stroke="black" stroke-width="2".

Comment: После подготовки изображения - всё заработало) Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать плавное появление с помощью `keyframes`:

```css
.grey-circle-path {
  animation: appearance 3s ease;
  fill: #000;
}

@keyframes appearance {
  from {
    fill: #fff
  }
  to {
    fill: #000
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0" class="grey-circle" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 115 115" enable-background="new 0 0 115 115" xml:space="preserve">
    <g opacity="0.15">
        <path class="grey-circle-path" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M57.5,3C87.6,3,112,27.4,112,57.5S87.6,112,57.5,112S3,87.6,3,57.5S27.4,3,57.5,3 M57.5,0   C25.7,0,0,25.7,0,57.5S25.7,115,57.5,115S115,89.3,115,57.5S89.3,0,57.5,0L57.5,0z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант, но мне скорее нужно чтобы элемент отрисовывался, как например тут https://jwn.gr/